Request Android client to update it's WebView
I've got a React app that is wrapped with Capacitor, to deploy an android app.
In my react code app I use new web features: structuredClone (js), and @starting style(css feature- that cannot be polyfilled). The starting style needs a Webview version of at least 117 (current updated is 127).
Now, one of my users has an android 14 device. This device runs an old WebView (Version 95.0.4638).
Is there a way to ask/tell users (programmatically) something like this:
In order for the app to run properly, please update you Webview ?
